# Ошибка приложение андроид вылетает

Tags: java, android

ошибка в приложении я сделал активити переход в которую по нажатию кнопки. В этой активити прописал код для добавления фото в firebase storage используя cropper image библиотеку и piccaso .

````
savenick_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (checker.equals("clicked")) {
                    ValidateControlers();

                } else {
                    ValidateAndSaveOnlyInfo();

                }
            }
        });
        plusphoto.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                checker = "clicked";
                CropImage.activity().setAspectRatio(1, 1).start(SettingaccActivity.this);
            }
        });
        getUserInfo();
    }




    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
            CropImage.ActivityResult result = CropImage.getActivityResult(data);
            imageUri = result.getUri();

            imageprof.setImageURI(imageUri);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Произошла ошибка", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }


    }

    private void ValidateControlers() {
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(nick_edit.getText().toString()))
            Toast.makeText(this, "Введите ние", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
else if( checker.equals("clicked"))
    {
        uploadProfilImage();
}

    private void uploadProfilImage() {
    final ProgressDialog progressDialog=new ProgressDialog(this);
    progressDialog.setTitle("Идет загрузка");
    progressDialog.setMessage("Пожалуйста подождите");
    progressDialog.show();
    if (imageUri !=null){
        final StorageReference fileRef= storageprofilpicsRef.child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()+"jpg");
        uploadTask=fileRef.putFile(imageUri);
        uploadTask.continueWithTask(new Continuation() {
            @Override
            public Object then(@NonNull Task task) throws Exception {
                if (!task.isSuccessful()){
                    throw  task.getException();
                }
                return fileRef.getDownloadUrl();
            }
        }).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Uri>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task <Uri>task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()){
                    Uri downloadUri=task.getResult();
                    myUri=downloadUri.toString();
                    HashMap<String,Object> userMap=new HashMap<>();
                    userMap.put("uid",mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid());
                    userMap.put("name",nick_edit.getText().toString());
                    userMap.put("image",myUri);

                    databaseReference.child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).updateChildren(userMap);
                    progressDialog.dismiss();

                    startActivity(new Intent(SettingaccActivity.this,HomeActivity.class));
                }
            }
        });
    }
    else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Изображение не выбрано", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    }
    private void ValidateAndSaveOnlyInfo() {
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(nick_edit.getText().toString()))
            Toast.makeText(this, "Введите ние", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
else{
        HashMap<String,Object> userMap=new HashMap<>();
        userMap.put("uid",mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid());
        userMap.put("name",nick_edit.getText().toString());


        databaseReference.child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).updateChildren(userMap);

        startActivity(new Intent(SettingaccActivity.this,HomeActivity.class));
    }
    private void getUserInfo() {
    databaseReference.child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.exists()&&snapshot.getChildrenCount()>0)
            {
                String name=snapshot.child("name").getValue().toString();
                nick_edit.setText(name);
                if (snapshot.hasChild("image")) {
                    String image = snapshot.child("image").getValue().toString();
                    Picasso.get().load(image).into(imageprof);
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });
    }```
````

Ошибка:

```
Process: mychati.app, PID: 31163
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{mychati.app/mychati.app.SettingaccActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo android.content.Context.getApplicationInfo()' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3455)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3699)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2135)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:236)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8056)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:656)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:967)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo android.content.Context.getApplicationInfo()' on a null object reference
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.getApplicationInfo(ContextWrapper.java:184)
        at android.view.ContextThemeWrapper.getTheme(ContextThemeWrapper.java:174)
        at android.app.AlertDialog.resolveDialogTheme(AlertDialog.java:245)
        at android.app.AlertDialog.<init>(AlertDialog.java:214)
        at android.app.AlertDialog.<init>(AlertDialog.java:210)
        at android.app.AlertDialog.<init>(AlertDialog.java:148)
        at android.app.ProgressDialog.<init>(ProgressDialog.java:99)
        at mychati.app.SettingaccActivity.uploadProfilImage(SettingaccActivity.java:117)
        at mychati.app.SettingaccActivity.<init>(SettingaccActivity.java:113)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
        at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(AppComponentFactory.java:95)
        at androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(CoreComponentFactory.java:45)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1254)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3443)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3699) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2135) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:236) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8056) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:656) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:967)**
```

Comment: Покажите в коде, где у вас строчка номер 117 в файле SettingaccActivity.java.

Comment: UploadProfilImage(); у нее снизу скобка она является 117строкой.

Answer (score 0):

Судя по stackTrace у вас где-то используется context равный null. Возможно в AlertDialog передаете не тот контекст? Где конкретно возникает ошибка можете отследить по синим ссылкам в вашем логе

Comment: Синим говорит самая первая строка:savenick_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

Comment: А почему используете ProgressDialog? Он устарел начиная с api 26. Возможно он и создаёт проблемы